# Concentration of measure for local martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

Can someone tell me, where I can find a proof of the following fact:

> Let $M$ be a continuous local martingale with $M_0=0$. Then we have
>   $$ P \left(\max_{s \leq t} \; M_s \geq y, \ [M]_t \leq C \right) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{y^2}{2C} \right) $$
>   for every $t, y, C> 0$.

Here I denote by $[M]_t$ the quadratic variation of $M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By a [time change argument](http://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/04/20/time-changed-brownian-motion/), we can express $M_t=B([M]_t)$ where $(B(w))_{w\geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion. 
The result now follows from the [maximal inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_inequality#Application%3a_Brownian_motion) for Brownian motion.

\begin{eqnarray}
P \left(\max_{s \leq t} \; M_s \geq y,  \left[M\right]_t \leq C \right) 
&=&  P \left(\max_{s \leq t} \; B([M]_s) \geq y, \ [M]_t \leq C \right) \cr
&\leq&  P \left(\max_{w \leq C} \; B(w) \geq y\right) \cr
&\leq&     \exp \left(\frac{-y^2}{2C} \right)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Great 3 line argument !!!